# How to obtain session in spring without request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

Is there a way to get current session in Spring MVC, but not by request. Typically what we do is we get request in Action/Controller class methods. From this request, we get session by request.getSession(). But is there a way to get this session without this request object?

My motive is that in one utility class I need to access a value that is set in session and this utility class method is getting accessed from more than 50 methods of Controller classes. If I have to get session from request then I would need to change all these 50 places. This looks quite tedious. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: read up on @SessionAttribues and find some examples online

Comment: Can't your override or `polymorph`ize the utility method of yours?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think my question is quite clear. Is there a way to get current session in Spring MVC, but not by request. This says it all. I want session object from some source other that request object.

Comment: I got the answer for the question. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can always retrive HttpSession out of Controller space without passing HttpServletRequest.

Spring provides listener that exposes the request to the current thread. You may refer [RequestContextListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html).

This listener should be registered in your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <description>Servlet listener that exposes the request to the current thread</description>
    <display-name>RequestContextListener</display-name>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

and this is how you can get details from Session.

```
public final User getUser() {

    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes();
    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes;
    HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(true);

    Object userObject = httpSession.getAttribute("WEB_USER");
    if (userObject == null) {
        return null;
    }

    User user = (User) userObject;
    return user;
}
```

Comment: I have added RequestContextListener in my web.xml, On first request i set attribute in session By using RequestContextHolder, in next call no attributes are in session . Any suggestion