# Different ways to get HttpSession Object without HttpServlerRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there any other way to get `HttpSession` object without `HttpServlertRequest` in java?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051326/how-to-obtain-session-in-spring-without-request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837285/differents-ways-to-get-servlet-context

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context (such as code) for anyone to be able to answer this question properly. For example you can get access to @SessionScoped attributes in CDI without direct access to a HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 1):

A session is by nature associated with a request from a specific user. So i don't think you will get a session object without request object.